# Java replace all String add quotations around all words but ignore periods

Tags: java, regex, string

So I am trying to take in a string and add quotation marks around each word for formatting purposes

```
String data = "JavaScript, Spring 4.0"
String result = data.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\"$1\"");
result = "[" + result + "]";             
System.out.println(result);
```

but it returns it like this: "JavaScript", "Spring" "4"."0"
anyway to ignore the period here?

Comment: `data.replaceAll("([\\w.]+)", "\"$1\"");`

Comment: What do you want it to return?  What do you mean by "ignore the period"?

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess that should be the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Include `.` in a character class:

```
data.replaceAll("([\\w.]+)", "\"$1\"")
                  ^    ^ Make a character class
                      ^  Add period to the class
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Regular Expression, the term `\w` refers to any word character (uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and underscore) which doesn't include a period.

You can expand the expression to include a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) - a set of characters - that include a period, like so:

```
[\w.]+
```

In the above expression, square brackets indicate a character class. I kept the original `\w` to match any word character, but also added a period. Since not all of your words have a period on them, the expression needs to match even if the period is not present. The `+` operator matches 1 or more items in the set defined by the character class.

Escaping the backslash in Java, your code should read as follows:

```
String result = data.replaceAll("([\\w.]+)", "\"$1\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `(\\S+)` instead of `(\\w+)`.

Statement: `String result = data.replaceAll("(\\S+)", "\"$1\"");`

Output: `["JavaScript," "Spring" "4.0"]`

And

Statement: `String result = data.replaceAll("\\.|\\,", "").replaceAll("(\\S+)", "\"$1\"");`

Output: `["JavaScript" "Spring" "40"]`

Comment: While your suggestion will work in the specific example in the original post, it will erroneously match punctuation, such as commas, dashes, etc. Additionally, your suggestion removes the period entirely - an undesired effect.

Comment: It will not. That's why I put 2 options. 2nd one to show a way that if you want any specific you can do that using the | (or condition in replaceAll). It depends entirely your requirement. First example shows that if you want to keep punctuation like comma, dashes etc. If you want to keep the them go for solution 1.

Comment: OP wanted to keep a period, such as in "4.0" specifically, but not commas, dashes, etc. Neither of your solutions accomplish this. In fact, the original example would include the comma after "JavaScript" in the first set of quotes using your first method, and will strip the period in your second method. None are what the OP requested.